# Anyway of creating a random data set between two values that fluctuates between 1-5% each interval?

Tags: excel, database, random, dataset

I need to create a data set of 750 data points that need to be between 100 and 130 but the value needs to move at least 1-5% each time and end at 130.

This is to represent the volatility of a share price over 3 trading years so has to show the natural rise and fall of a share price.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might start you off:

Cell A1 just has a max() function, the formula in A4 is :

```
=RANDBETWEEN(100,125)*1+RANDBETWEEN(1,4)+RANDBETWEEN(1,10)/10
```

[image]

Just drag down as far as...

Comment: The problem is the value that needs to be +/- x% needs to correlate to the most recent number produced so cant just be random from between 100 and 130, e.g. cell A5 needs to be +/- x% to cell A4 so you dont have these jumps from 108 to 119 otherwise it won't look like a upward trending but with falls like a share price.

But thank you for this as helped me think about how this is going to work, if you have any more ideas I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Then you should find that easy to do and good practice... hint, edit the function in a5 so the first randbetween() is deleted and points to cell A4, then think how you would decide between a +1 and -1...

Comment: You've lost me here, don't understand the rand function enough.

Comment: Separate it out and try it.